# Insert DateTime which has no value

Tags: vb.net, datetime, ms-access

I'm running an `If` statement before my `INSERT`, to compare whether or not a date has been entered. If a value has been entered, I'm assigning this value to a variable (used as a parameter value), but if no value has been entered, I need to literally enter nothing, so that when loading the data, the format is still __ /__ /__

However, when inserting it using `datevar = Nothing` it is inserting it as 01/01/2001. I've also tried using DBNull.Value, but this kept saying `DBNull.Value cannot be converted to type 'Date'`

How can I get the query to insert nothing/null so that it returns __ /__/ __?

```
Dim delDate As Date

If dr.Item("Goods_Delivered") = False Then
    delivVal = 0
    delivVol = 0
    sino = ""
    delDate = DBNull.Value
Else
    Try
        delivVal = dr.Item("deliveryVal")
        delivVol = dr.Item("deliveryVol")
        sino = dr.Item("Supplier_Invoice_Number")
        delDate = dr.Item("Final_Delivery")
    Catch ex As Exception
        delivVal = 0
        delivVol = 0
        sino = 0
    End Try
End If
```

Comment: *How* are you using `DbNull`?  Is the date column marked as required? "__ /__/ __"  is not a date, so that part is also unclear.

Comment: @Plutonix No, the field is not required in the database. I don't want to actually insert __/ __/ __, I just need to insert a value that will fill the calendar picker this way when opening the form (Which is why I was trying to insert Null or Nothing in the first place)

Comment: Also, I was using it like 'datevar = DBNull.Value`

Comment: DBNull is a database thing, you can set that column to DBNull but a DateTime var cannot be.  You should [edit] your post to show the insert code

Comment: @Plutonix In that case, how would I only insert it as null if no date was chosen?

Comment: how about declaring `deldate` as variant then use null.

Comment: That is not INSERT code, but if I assume `dr` is a DateReader, you can use `dr.IsDBNull(index)` to see if there is a date saved.  The **next** problem is that if you are using a DateTimePicker, they *always* have a valid DateTime, so you cant set that to Nothing/blank

Comment: @Plutonix Sorry, misread your initial comment about the code! I'm not using a DateTimePicker, however, this is all being done via an `UltraWinGrid`

Comment: @winghei Thank you, I actually made it an Object variable, but this worked either way

Comment: You might also want to use a `Nullable(Of DateTime)` for the variable so it can store Nothing or a value.  (`Dim myDate As DateTime?`)  Dont use `Object`

Answer (score 0):

Initialize delDate to DateTime.MinValue

```
Dim delDate as Date = #1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM#
```

Then when you construct your insert statement, check if delDate = DateTime.MinValue. If it does, insert NULL. Otherwise insert delDate.